# cpp / c++ get pointer value or depointerize pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I was wondering if it's possible to make a pointer not a pointer..

The problem is I have a function that accepts a pointer for an paramater for me to easily get a value to that pointer. It's a simple int so I was wondering if I could just get that value without needing to send around a pointer wherever I want the value to land.

I don't want the function to return the value as an int as it's giving a value to 2 pointers!

Comment: If you only need the value, just pass by value.

Comment: Have you heard about dereferencing a pointer?

Comment: If you want the value of an pointer, just de-reference the pointer, you don't need a function to return the value of the pointer. Your English is not very good, can you show some code of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Am I the only one that feel like Todd Hockney right now ?

Comment: I am creating a function that accepts an int. And the variable that I want to send to that function is currently a pointer and I don't want to send the whole pointer, just the value.

Comment: E, Rasmus......

Answer (score 109, accepted):

To get the value of a pointer, just de-reference the pointer.

```
int *ptr;
int value;
*ptr = 9;

value = *ptr;
```

value is now 9.

I suggest you read more about pointers, this is their base functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the original value from a pointer referenced to a const *void one can, for instance, code it like below:

```
// const* void vars[j].address;

double* tmp = (double*) vars[j].address;
double tmpv = *tmp;
Serial.println( tmpv );
```