# Get value from memory address

Tags: c++, pointers

I have an `int*` variable that stores memory address, for the example address `0x28c1150`.

I want to know, what value is stored at the address.

edit:

```
struct list {
    int value;
    list *next;
    list *head = NULL;
    void push(int n);
    void select();
    void pop();
    void top();

};

void list::push(int value) {
    list *temp = new list;

    temp->value = value;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}
void list::top(){
    list * temp = new list;

    cout << head;
}
```

i want to print top of my list

Comment: Or for the value that is being pointed to: `std::cout << *variable << "\n";`

Comment: You can't have a value without also having a *type*. What type of value are you expecting?

Comment: im expecting int

Comment: Then @Blaze has already given you the answer.

Comment: @NoobXDDD Then `cout << *variable << '\n';` Does that not work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cpp / c++ get pointer value or depointerize pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420257/cpp-c-get-pointer-value-or-depointerize-pointer)

Comment: @NoobXDDD You realise you've completely changed the question? Why didn't you supply this information *at the start*. Do you think we have psychic powers?

Comment: Please read ["What is the XY Problem?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Every little bit of information and edit you add shows more and more that's what you asked here.

Comment: And how is `int*`  related to your code. I don't see any `int*` in your code.

Comment: Your `top()` function leaks memory. You allocate a new list and then just forget about it.

Comment: no match for operator << (operand type are std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and list

Comment: @TedLyngmo i know i will do it later

Comment: @NoobXDDD You are trying answers to the question everyone **thought** you asked. Try this instead `cout << head->value;`

Comment: @john that works thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is a `list*`:

```
list* variable = new list;
variable->top();
```

...but note that your current `top()` function leaks memory since you allocate a new list every time it's called and you just forget about it. Try this instead:

```
int list::top(){  
    return head->value;
}

std::cout << variable->top() << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that works fine, but can you tell me how to use this value in my code (in if to compare something)

Comment: `int other_value = 10; if(variable->top() == other_value) ...` ? I think you should edit your original question to make it clear what you are actually asking about. Right now it's put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

You have to dereference the pointer:

```
template<class T>
void print_value_at(T* pointer) {
    T& value = *pointer; //get value in pointer
    // print value 
    std::cout << value <<std::endl;
}
```

If the pointer is void, you have to cast it to whatever type it was originally:

```
int x = 10;
// get void pointer to x
void* x_pointer_as_void = (void*)&x; 
// convert it back to a pointer to an int:
int* x_pointer = (int*)x_pointer_as_void;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is (based on current version of question)

```
cout << head->value;
```