# C++ invalid argument at memory location error

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Im trying to read a single byte from a binary file and convert it into a bitset, and print it to the console however the following code raises an error.

```
ifstream test(filePath, ios::in | ios::binary);
char * byte = new char;
test.read(byte, 1);
cout << std::bitset<8>(byte);
```

Unhandled exception at 0x757DA842 in program.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x006FEBE4.

I cant seem to figure out what is wrong and have tried a variety of things, any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to dereference `byte` when passing it to `std::bitset`'s constructor.

---

Take a look at the reference for [`std::bitset`'s constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset).

You seem to want to call constructor number (2) on that page:

```
bitset(unsigned long long)
```

To construct a `bitset` representing the bits of the `char` pointed to by `byte`.

You're *actually* calling constructor number (4) (with `CharT = char`):

```
template< class CharT >
explicit bitset(
    const CharT* str,
    typename std::basic_string<CharT>::size_type
        n = std::basic_string<CharT>::npos,
    CharT zero = CharT('0'),
    CharT one = CharT('1')
)
```

With the default `std::string::npos` for the second argument, this assumes the pointer passed as `str` points to a C-style nul-terminated string of `'0'` and `'1'` characters and tries to construct the `bitset` from those.

Answer (score 0):

`byte` in the final line `std::bitset<8>(byte)` isn't a character but a pointer.

Edit to `std::bitset<8>(*byte)` than code new code should work.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14420297/6776992) for more detail.